# How can i check Blue-tooth Le( Low energy) support or Not?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-ndk, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to check my device support Blue tooth LE or Not. How can i check that?

Any SDK is available or Not

Thank You

Comment: and, what have you done so far ?

Comment: @Lucifer I know Motorola provide sdk with Blue-tooth Le ok
check this link

http://developer.motorola.com/docs/bluetooth-low-energy-gatt-framework-api/#Methods_used_by_Bluetooth_LE_profiles__connectGatt

Comment: what i am saying is , if you have any error in your code, the please show us, we will help, this site is for that purpose. But if you are asking for **ready-made code**, then it is totally wrong.

Comment: @Lucifer By the way I am working on android source code and changing core structure of android.

Comment: I talking about any sdk who help to connect bluetooth LE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are many phones with BLE, but only iPhone and Motorlla support them properly.

You have to have fully set android sdk and then use one of API to use BLE on your phone fpr development:

**Motorola API**
http://developer.motorola.com/docs/bluetooth-low-energy-gatt-framework-api/

**Broadcom API** (HTC One and Samsung Galaxy s 3)
http://code.google.com/p/broadcom-ble/

Comment: Unlike the two specified directly above, the HTC One X+ and the HTC Droid DNA supports BLE out of the box (no rooting or installation of libraries required) you can use the chipset dependent API from Broadcom or the chipset independent API from HTC.

Comment: Why would you say "unlike". Motorola Droid Razr and iPhone 4S supports them really well - and with no rooting and stuff. I have worked with both.

Answer (score 0):

As of API 18 Android now has native support for this.

From the documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

You can now do the following:

```
// Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device. Then
// you can selectively disable BLE-related features.
if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
}
```